# How to set HTTP headers on Camel http4 endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

How does one set the headers for a request made using the http4 component in Camel? The site I'm connecting to requires the referrer header to be set. Using HttpClient directly, one can add headers to the request, but I can't see how that's exposed in Camel.

ETA: Working example based on the accepted answer:

```
 from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=300000")
      .setHeader("Referer", constant("https://example.com"))
      .to("https4://www.example.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to set it as a header in the Camel route (if you use that)

```
setHeader("referrer", constant("MyValue"))
```

Though your question is a bit too vague how you use Camel http4 component to send the request.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually gave up and came to the same conclusion through digging through the source. I'll update the question with an example of how this is being used.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this behavior? We have larger route and when camel adds all header values to hettp request, the http request becomes too big and gets rejected. We are using simple http component.

Comment: I do this `message.setHeader("Retry-After", constant(120));` but in a CXF server context, but it does not work as-is, is there any other option to do it?