# How to set "Referer" header in Apache Camel route?

Tags: apache, apache-camel, http-referer

Do anyone know how to set "Referer" header in Apache Camel DSL?
I do below. It doesn't work.

```
<setHeader headerName="Referer">
                <constant>ttttt</constant>
            </setHeader>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please show us your route because only this header setting is not enough information.

I found a similar question where this header is used:
[how-to-set-http-headers-on-camel-http4-endpoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088722/how-to-set-http-headers-on-camel-http4-endpoint)

Comment: I tried set header in blue print DSL, it doesn't work.
<from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:30100/jetty/test/address" />
<setHeader headerName="Referer">
    <constant>WWW.TEST.COM</constant>
   </setHeader> 
<to uri="jetty://http://services.test/address/address"/>
Do I have to set route in class instead of in xml???

Comment: It does not matter whether you write it as XML or in Java.
You has a ";" in your from element which should be removed.

Comment: Please vote me up or mark it at answered when I solved the problem.
Regards lahu89